# limiting number of characters in regexp_like

Tags: regex, oracle, regular-language

I am mining text fields for terms such as home births, delivered at home, etc etc. 
I have code below that mostly works. However, how can I limit the number of characters to limit the number of false positives I might be getting?

I would want lines 1 & 2 but not 3. I am looking to limit the number of characters within the regexp_like statement to 10 or 20
so I would get home delivery or delivery at home.

```
with test (id, col) as
  (select 1, 'abc 3/4/16 blah blah home  delivery'                          from dual union all
   select 2, 'abc 3/4/16 blah blah 3/7/16 delivery at home xxx cc2'         from dual union all
   select 3, 'xxx 3/5/18 delivery 234 imp happened on 5/8/19 sent home 23f' from dual union all
   select 4, '3/10/18 bla bla imp-3/9/17 xfe 334 3/4/13 x'                  from dual
  )
select * from test 
where     regexp_like(col,'(home|deliver).*(deliv|birth|home)') ;
```

Thank you-

Comment: Thanks Lawrence Block.  Is your requirement to limit the length between certain words in the `regexp_like`?  Or just to limit the total length of the string?  If just to limit the total length, `AND LENGTH(col) < N` is all that is required.

Comment: Requirement is to limit length between certain words within the regexp_like-

Comment: Thanks Lawrence Block.  You want to allow only N characters maximum between `home|deliver` and `delev|birth|home`?  Is there something more specific?

Comment: @alexgibbs-Yes, that is all I am looking for so that 'home delivery' is captured or 'delivered at home'  but NOT 'normal delivery blah blah blah patient sent home'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are otherwise satisfied with the matches and performance you are getting,
you can limit the length of intervening characters between the `home|deliver` group and `deliv|birth|home` group by replacing the unbounded `.*` with a length-limited any-character matcher.

You can specify the allowed max-length and min-length of intervening characters in the string.
An example is below, that allows 0 - 30 characters between the groups.

```
WITH TEST (ID , COL) AS
    (SELECT 1, 'abc 3/4/16 blah blah home  delivery' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 2, 'abc 3/4/16 blah blah 3/7/16 delivery at home xxx cc2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 3, 'xxx 3/5/18 delivery 234 imp happened on 5/8/19 sent home 23f' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 4, '3/10/18 bla bla imp-3/9/17 xfe 334 3/4/13 x' FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
FROM TEST
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(COL , '(home|deliver).{0,30}(deliv|birth|home)');
```

Result:

```
   ID                                                     COL
_____ _______________________________________________________
    1 abc 3/4/16 blah blah home  delivery
    2 abc 3/4/16 blah blah 3/7/16 delivery at home xxx cc2


2 rows selected.
```

Comment: I was close. Instead I was using [] brackets and that did not work. Many thanks.